# How to fix ' com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout 50000000;'

Tags: spring-boot

```
#View Resolver
spring:
  mvc:
    view:
      prefix: /Views/
      suffix: .jsp
  mail:
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 587
    username: kunupradhan320@gmail.com
    password: password
    properties:
     mail:
       smtp: 
        starttls: 
          enable: true
          required: true
        auth: true
```

Comment: Can you Telnet to that same port from the machine you're running your code on?

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things to take care of while working with mail api in java.

1.You might be experiencing this issue because Antivirus would block sending email. You should temporarily disable your antivirus during sending email.

2.Setting with the email id.

Go to ***`Gmail`*** <kbd>Settings</kbd> **>** <kbd>Accounts and Import</kbd> **>** <kbd>Other Google Account settings</kbd> **>** and under <kbd>Sign-in & security</kbd>

1. <kbd>**2-Step Verification: Off**</kbd>
2. <kbd>**Allow less secure apps: ON**</kbd>
3. <kbd>**App Passwords:   1 password**</kbd> (16 characters long), later replaced the current password with this.

3.Try with 465 port also if that works.